# Underwater scene too "blurry"

Tags: blur

I'm trying to make a small video presentation of an rc submarine that rotate 360 degrees for demonstration.
Therefore , I have my underwater scene set up and everything but the problem is that the submarine is blurry and lack contrast with its environment . And because it's a presentation video to show off the sub , it's very important to have it clear and sharp even underwater .
Here is a rendered image [image]

Comment: You may want to post a screencap of your water volume material Shader nodes.  I would think that adjusting some Volume Absorption density lower or IOR if they exist -- but I can only guess with the minimal amount of information you have here.

Comment: Well, the blurriness and lack of contrast is of course due to your underwater environment, the density and color of the volume. Simplest thing would be to reduce the density. The question is: do you want/need the water density as it is? And if so, do you just want to reduce its effect on the submarine or should the submarine look like there were no volumetrics at all? Depending on what you want there are different solutions.